# How to migrate legacy function exec_SELECT_mm_query to Doctrine based Querybuilder / Connection in TYPO3

Tags: typo3

Assume the following code snippet:

```
$res = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECT_mm_query(
    $foreign . '.*', $local, $mm, $foreign, 'AND ' . $local . '.uid=' . $constraintUid);

while ($r=$GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
...
```

- $foreign / foreign: name of foreign DB table
- $local / local: name of local DB table
- $mm / mm : name of relation DB table (typically somethingorother_mm)
- $constraintUid / constraintUid: some uid

I would like to migrate code to TYPO3 9 using the Doctrine based database functions.

---

The above code gets converted to the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT foreign.* FROM local,mm,foreign 
    WHERE    local.uid=mm.uid_local 
        AND  foreign.uid=mm.uid_foreign 
        AND  local.uid = constraintUid
```

---

see [exec_SELECT_mm_query](https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/current/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_database_1_1_database_connection.html#a7e954e50312403831a74d3013ef96f0b):

Parameters:

- string   $select Field list for SELECT
- string   $local_table    Tablename, local table
- string   $mm_table   Tablename, relation table
- string   $foreign_table  Tablename, foreign table
- string   $whereClause    Optional additional WHERE clauses put in 
  the end of the query. ...
- ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be:

```
$foreign = 'a';
$mm = 'mm';
$local = 'b';
$item = 1;

/** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Query\QueryBuilder $queryBuilder */
$queryBuilder = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool::class
)->getQueryBuilderForTable($foreign);
$expr = $queryBuilder->expr();

/** @var \Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Statement $rows */
$rows = $queryBuilder
    ->select('foreign.*')
    ->from($foreign, 'foreign')
    ->innerJoin('foreign', $mm, 'mm', $expr->eq('foreign.uid', 'mm.uid_foreign'))
    ->innerJoin('mm', $local, 'local', $expr->eq('mm.uid_local', 'local.uid'))
    ->where(
        $expr->eq('local.uid', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($item, \PDO::PARAM_INT))
    )
    ->execute();

while (($row = $rows->fetch()) != null) {
}
```

Comment: This is very similar to my solution (innerJoin() = join(). But using $expr makes the expressions shorter.

Comment: The biggest benefit in my solution is the usage of table aliases which make the where part better readable. Beside that, you are right, is the same.